# What should be covered in a performance review?

Tags: management, performance-reviews

The small company I am working for never had performance reviews. Because the employees were either part-time or co-founders, there was never a need for them (each person had a stake in the company, and any things that needed to be worked on were discussed relatively openly in company-wide meetings).

Due to the success of the business, we have started hiring new full-time employees who have been asking for us to have formal performance reviews. We asked them what they were looking for from those reviews (since we have never really done them), and they wanted:

1. To understand how their performance meets our expectations
2. To give an opportunity to review career goals and future prospects in the company
3. To give them a chance to give us feedback on our management

Since we plan to continue to grow in the future, we do feel we need to establish some sort of formal process. Understanding that this will be a work in progress, we want to give it a shot. What are the essential ingredients to a successful performance review?

Comment: Are you looking at a specific industry ?

Comment: Feel free to be industry agnostic.

Comment: We have ongoing discussions, but the employees are requesting regular (quarterly? semi-annual? annual?) formal reviews as well.

Comment: Haven't your employees already given you what you need to cover in that list?

Comment: I would be overjoyed if someone would get rid of the big time-waster that is performance reviews. Are they really asking for formal reviews or do they see that as the only way they can get raises or bonuses? Maybe they are really asking something different than you think they are.

Comment: @HLGEM - If you ever want to provide anyone with a great book on the subject, may I recommend:  http://www.amazon.com/Management-Practices-Waste-Money-instead/dp/093710017X

Comment: I usually point them to the work of Deming.

Comment: @HLGEM They are asking for 'official' opportunities to make sure they are meeting our expectations, to make sure we are respecting their career goals, and to give them an opportunity to give us feedback on how we're doing. Whether or not this constitutes a 'formal' review or not is beyond our understanding.