# How to prepare for a meeting about promotion and career plans

Tags: software-industry, career-development, united-states, promotion, performance-reviews

During the last performance review with my manager, he mentioned that if I maintain the level of performance I can expect promotion in a few months and talk about my career. What does it involve and how should I prepare for it?

**EDIT** To clarify - I don't want to know how to achieve promotion as I have a good idea (well - my boss said what I need to do) but rather how should I prepare for questions about my career - I don't want to be caught off-guard and need to answer "I don't know - I'd need to think about it".

**EDIT** Answering questions from comments. This is my first job out of college (Master's degree) though I had some internships before. I worked for 2 years during which I worked on several projects collaborating with other teams, mentored an intern etc. I've already had a few performance reviewes and raises. I'll take another look as I assumed that preformance reviews are closer to what I already had rather then discussion about future development.

Comment: Your recent edit makes this question very broad, as the answer depends on the questions your boss might ask during the meeting. And there are millions of questions to pick from.  (Flagging)

Comment: I want more detail:  **1.** How long have you worked at this company?  **2.** how much total experience do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prepare for first performance review](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23421/how-to-prepare-for-first-performance-review)

Comment: A meeting where you talk about your career and possibly get a promotion or raise on the spot is called a "performance review". There have been a lot of questions about them on this site already. These questions are likely to help you prepare for the meeting and know what to expect, though every company is different so your review may not be exactly like anyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it involve and how should I prepare for it?

The solution is in your boss's words: `if you maintain the level of performance you can expect promotion`

As simple as that. You continue to do your work as you are doing it now.

Some suggestions:

Don't try to impress your job now with working overtime or doing favours. Just work how you are doing now, and expect a promotion any time soon.

So, don't **prepare** for it. Just wait for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems that I was a bit unclear. I didn't want to know how to achive the promotion (as you said that was whot my boss said) but rather what can I expect from talk about carieer plans.

Answer (score 0):

Be prepared to talk about what career trajectory you want to take.  For example do you want to work towards a managerial role or a specialized technical role.

Be prepared to talk about what your limitations are regarding relocation, travel, or working hours.  For example there are many roles that you shouldn't be working towards if you are set on a 40 hour week maximum.

Be prepared to talk industry and company specifics about what interests you.  For example are there any teams or projects that have caught your interest.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're going to be asked in which direction you want to go. Not enough info to give a better answer, but I would imagine it's to do with which area of expertise will you focus on and what specialities suit you best. Many companies have several paths that a new employee can follow once they have proven themselves capable of learning and working satisfactorily. For instance someone with a basic qualification such as MCP could do a stint with engineering and then decide they want to move into a graphic design role, or networking, or routing, or sys admin.

You should look at the different paths they have at the company and put some thought into which you would like to see yourself in, in general terms.