# Performance Review do and dont's

Tags: performance-reviews, probation

I have performance review and it is within my probation period. While I never had one before and generally I find many question regarding performance review after a 1 year in a job.

I am curious to know what goes in the meeting and what are the the do and don'ts of discussing it in meeting despite your review going bad, good or worse. (Although I had been lagging behind my task)

Comment: "*what are the the do and don'ts of discussing it in meeting*" What is "it"? What are you really asking here? What [the point is of a review](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58224/purpose-of-performance-review)?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of the things you should look for during the performance or probationary review based on my experience as a software engineer and manager.

### Do

1. Look for goal \ objectives.  Make sure they are **clearly measurable**.  Vague objectives or goals that are not easily measurable can be very difficult to obtain.  ( *Most reviews have future goals/objectives* )
2. *Take any criticism with a grain of salt*.  In other words just absorb what is said and think on it.  If necessary, request a separate meeting to review any points that you did not agree with or are unclear on.
3. Ask for things to help you get better, such as training, tools, etc.

### Don't

1. Over react to criticism.  Taking this feedback can be difficult, but you will need to learn to do this in order to grow.  Also try to consider that your manager might be right.
2. Don't leave the review and begin talking bad about the process to your co-workers.  This does nothing but **make you look like an angry little person**.
3. Use caution in any reactions you have to a negative review.  *Remember HR is not your friend*, so unless its pretty egregious I would not consider HR as a resource here.

---

Answer (score 4):

It's just to discuss your performance so far and see if you need any help or have questions.  Think of it more as a catch-up meeting.

Generally these probation meetings are along the lines of

> We're happy with your work so far, we'll be pleased to retain you after your probation period

or

> We're happy with you so far, but there's a few things we need to work on

There's no set dos and don'ts - it's just a confirmation that you're a good fit for the role or not.  Usually, it's positive in nature - if you're not a good fit for the role this soon, it's an indication that the interview process has failed in some way.

Comment: Can I input to say what slowed me down on days or weeks and what didn't?

Comment: @cookieMonster, you can but they will take most things you say as an excuse. It is better to own up to a problem and then work on fixing it that to try to excuse it away. If you had genuine delays, your boss should have been informed of them at the time they happened.